# which PyTorch version is correct?

Tags: python, pytorch

So, I had downloaded CUDA 11.2 for tensorflow keras, which worked great, but now I want to use pytorch for reinforcement learning, and currently pytorch only has two options for CUDA version for pip downloads, 10.2 and 11.3

If possible I don't wanna upgrade to cuda 11.3 or downgrade to 10.2, without doing that is it possible to download pytorch for a cuda version that is not recommended for?
Like will 10.2 recommended pytorch work for cuda 11.2 version

Comment: The PyTorch build you install must have access to the exact CUDA version is was built against

Comment: Here you can find a complete list of pytorch wheels: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/. I believe cu111 should also work (search for "cu111" in that page), since I am using "torch+cu111" and my system has cuda 11.2 and everything works fine

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/veritas9872/PyTorch-Universal-Docker-Template

Please try out this repository. It contains a template to build any version of PyTorch on any version of CUDA, cuDNN, Python, etc.

Please star it if you find it useful!

Comment: You can use the repository here to build a pip wheel for any version of PyTorch on any version of CUDA. Simply extract the wheel to your current environment to use it.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing an example on how to use the repository.